# View changes not being reflected when made change is made inside delegate method

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a class `A` which has delegates . The delegates are being implemented in another class `B`.

In `B` I have a text field , which I am trying to make hidden when the delegate is called.

```
- (void) didRecieveResponseDelegate : (BOOL) status{
      textField.hidden = YES;
}
```

But the textField doesnt get hidden. I've noticed none of the view related changes work inside the delegate including removing of child view controllers. What's the problem and how do I fix it ?

EDIT : B is a child view controller of another view controller

Comment: Have you added a.delegate = self; in class B? Can you add log to didRecieveResponseDelegate: to make sure this method is called?

Comment: did you check it out either didrecieveResponseDelegate method calling or not

Comment: Yes I've made sure the delegate is called. All logs work inside the delegate. But I'm not able to remove any views or change the visiblity of elements

Comment: Show the code where you set the delegate. Are you actually using 2 different instances of the `B` class?

Comment: Is didRecieveResponseDelegate called on the main thread or a background thread?

Comment: Its called from a asychronous network call using NSURLSession.

Comment: Try perform the UI changes on main thread.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
- (void) didRecieveResponseDelegate : (BOOL) status{

     dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
             textField.hidden = YES;
     });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Does the method get called? (Breakpoint or NSLog to prove it).
2. Why are you using instance variables with leading underscore? That leads to bugs and confusion as well as distrust in your code.
3. Is textField actually set or is it nil? NSLog to prove it.
4. Fix spelling errors in method names. Quite possible that didReceiveResponseDelegate is called instead of didRecieveResponseDelegate.
5. Make sure you don't make UI calls from a background thread.

Comment: Everything you said is check and is fine. The only thing to note here is B is a child view controller of another controller, if that helps